# Installing mysql-python on Centos

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get the MySQL-python lib installed on centos 5.5.  I ran

```
sudo yum install MySQL-python
```

but then when I tried:

```
import MySQLdb
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 22, in ?
    raise ImportError("this is MySQLdb version %s, but _mysql is version %r" %
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0), \ # added linebreak
but _mysql is version (1, 2, 1, 'final', 1)
```

any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did not install MySQL via yum? The version of MySQLDB in the repository is tied to the version of MySQL in the repository. The versions need to match.

Your choices are:

1. Install the RPM version of MySQL.
2. Compile MySQLDB to your version of
   MySQL.

Comment: Pretty sure I did install MySQL via yum, but that was some time ago so am not positive.  I might go and uninstall it now then re-install it via yum to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Just tried reinstalling mysql, mysqlserver and mysqldb from yum, but still have the same error msg.  I'll try your second solution now.

Comment: Rebuilt MySQL-python-1.2.3 from source and now up and running.

Comment: sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-lib
sudo yum install MySQL-python
pip install mysql-python

Comment: @romuloigor that's awesome, you fixed my problems :) You should add this as an answer (I'll del mine if you do), it looks like a lot of people haven't figured it out. . Edit though: it's _mysql-libs_, not _mysql-lib_

Answer (score 41):

**Step 1** - Install package

```
# yum install MySQL-python
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-python.i686 0:1.2.3-3.fc15 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package              Arch         Version                 Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 MySQL-python         i686         1.2.3-3.fc15            fedora          78 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 78 k
Installed size: 220 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Setting up and reading Presto delta metadata
Processing delta metadata
Package(s) data still to download: 78 k
MySQL-python-1.2.3-3.fc15.i686.rpm                       |  78 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : MySQL-python-1.2.3-3.fc15.i686                               1/1 

Installed:
  MySQL-python.i686 0:1.2.3-3.fc15                                              

Complete!
```

**Step 2** - Test working

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydb" )
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
data = cursor.fetchone()    
print "Database version : %s " % data    
db.close()
```

**Ouput:**

```
Database version : 5.5.20
```

Answer (score 11):

I have **Python 2.7.5, MySQL 5.6 and CentOS  7.1.1503**.

For me it worked with the following command:

```
# pip install mysql-python
```

**Note pre-requisites here:**

Install Python pip:

```
# rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

# yum -y update
Reboot the machine (if kernel is also updated)

# yum -y install python-pip
```

Install Python devel packages:

```
# yum install python-devel
```

Install MySQL devel packages:

```
# yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: you also have to install gcc with `yum install gcc`

Comment: what about python3?

Answer (score 7):

For centos7 I required:

`sudo yum install mysql-devel gcc python-pip python-devel
sudo pip install mysql-python`

So, `gcc` and `mysql-devel` (rather than `mysql`) were important

Answer (score 1):

`mysql-python` **NOT** support **Python3**, you may need:

```
sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Also, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724855/6779334) for more alternatives.