# No module named MySQLdb even if MySQL-python installed?

Tags: python, mysql, unix, centos, mysql-python

I have a CentOS box.

```
(venv)[root@localhost]# yum install MySQL-python
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.maine.edu
 * epel: ftp.osuosl.org
 * extras: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * remi: rpms.famillecollet.com
 * updates: mirrors.centarra.com
Setting up Install Process
Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

...

```
(venv)[root@localhost]# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, May 20 2014, 20:23:08)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
>>>
```

What do I do?

and when I try `pip install mysql-python` I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/project/venv/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/user1/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/user1/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: maybe check that link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380931/installing-mysql-python-on-centos

Comment: @Freelancer but that's not the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: Could be related to your venv.  Did you create venv on the system and load a requirements file?

When you freeze the virtual environment, what does the requirments list say( pip freeze > requirements.txt)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/10970547/285594

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to force `pip` to use the default localization settings. Instead of:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

do:

```
LC_ALL=C pip install mysql-python
```

If you run into an `error: Python.h: No such file or directory`, then you'll need to install an additional library:

```
yum install python-devel
```

Comment: This worked! I had to `yum install mysql-devel` too, along with the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Some times we need to externally add/install git repo,
This is not released yet but you can add from below command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python.git
```

And

```
pip install mysql-python
```

and

```
yum install python-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL-python

For centos

**yum install MySQL-python**

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    >> import MySQLdb
    >>
```