# Installing MySQLdb for python2.7 in RHEL 6

Tags: python, django, mysql-python, rhel

I am trying to get django 1.9 running in RHEL 6. I have installed python2.7 and when I try to install MySQLdb, I get the errors shown below. I have googled and googled and tried many different things, all with no success. Can anyone please let me know how I can get this going?

```
# /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 110kB 3.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SPMNQU/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QrpP1S-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
    _mysql.c:44:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
    _mysql.c:46:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
    _mysql.c:47:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
    _mysql.c:48:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
    _mysql.c:88: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
    _mysql.c:102: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_Exception’:
    _mysql.c:146: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_errno’
    _mysql.c:146: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:149: error: ‘CR_MAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:149: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    _mysql.c:149: error: for each function it appears in.)
    _mysql.c:161: error: ‘CR_COMMANDS_OUT_OF_SYNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:162: error: ‘ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:163: error: ‘ER_SYNTAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:164: error: ‘ER_PARSE_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:165: error: ‘ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:166: error: ‘ER_WRONG_DB_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:167: error: ‘ER_WRONG_TABLE_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:168: error: ‘ER_FIELD_SPECIFIED_TWICE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:169: error: ‘ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:170: error: ‘ER_UNSUPPORTED_EXTENSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:171: error: ‘ER_TABLE_MUST_HAVE_COLUMNS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:200: error: ‘ER_DUP_ENTRY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:246: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_error’
    _mysql.c:246: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_server_init’:
    _mysql.c:351: warning: label ‘finish’ defined but not used
    _mysql.c:268: warning: unused variable ‘item’
    _mysql.c:267: warning: unused variable ‘groupc’
    _mysql.c:267: warning: unused variable ‘i’
    _mysql.c:267: warning: unused variable ‘cmd_argc’
    _mysql.c:266: warning: unused variable ‘s’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_Initialize’:
    _mysql.c:406: error: ‘MYSQL_RES’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:406: error: ‘result’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:411: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:411: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:425: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    _mysql.c:428: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_use_result’
    _mysql.c:428: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:430: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_store_result’
    _mysql.c:430: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:431: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:434: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_field_count’
    _mysql.c:434: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:438: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:442: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_num_fields’
    _mysql.c:443: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘nfields’
    _mysql.c:444: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:448: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_fetch_fields’
    _mysql.c:489: error: ‘BINARY_FLAG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:512: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_traverse’:
    _mysql.c:526: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:527: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_clear’:
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_Initialize’:
    _mysql.c:551: error: ‘MYSQL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:551: error: ‘conn’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:584: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:585: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:636: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_init’
    _mysql.c:636: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:639: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_options’
    _mysql.c:639: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:639: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:655: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:655: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_COMPRESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:656: error: ‘CLIENT_COMPRESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:659: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:659: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_NAMED_PIPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:661: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:661: error: ‘MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:663: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:663: error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:665: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:665: error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:668: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:668: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:676: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_real_connect’
    _mysql.c:676: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:694: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:702: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_traverse’:
    _mysql.c:783: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:784: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_clear’:
    _mysql.c:792: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:792: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:792: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:792: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:793: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_close’:
    _mysql.c:808: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:810: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_close’
    _mysql.c:810: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:812: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_affected_rows’:
    _mysql.c:834: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:835: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_affected_rows’
    _mysql.c:835: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_debug’:
    _mysql.c:851: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_debug’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_dump_debug_info’:
    _mysql.c:869: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:871: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_dump_debug_info’
    _mysql.c:871: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit’:
    _mysql.c:895: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_query’
    _mysql.c:895: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_autocommit’:
    _mysql.c:912: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:912: error: ‘SERVER_STATUS_AUTOCOMMIT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_commit’:
    _mysql.c:932: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback’:
    _mysql.c:954: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_errno’:
    _mysql.c:1070: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1071: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_error’:
    _mysql.c:1086: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1090: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_escape_string’:
    _mysql.c:1123: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_escape_string’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_escape’:
    _mysql.c:1252: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_describe’:
    _mysql.c:1332: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1332: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1335: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1336: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1337: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1348: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘IS_NOT_NULL’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_field_flags’:
    _mysql.c:1368: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1368: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1371: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1372: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1373: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: At top level:
    _mysql.c:1419: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_tuple’:
    _mysql.c:1425: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1427: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_fetch_lengths’
    _mysql.c:1427: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1430: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:1431: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c: At top level:
    _mysql.c:1444: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict’:
    _mysql.c:1449: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1449: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1451: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1453: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1454: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1457: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:1458: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c: At top level:
    _mysql.c:1483: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict_old’:
    _mysql.c:1488: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1488: error: ‘fields’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1490: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1492: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1493: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1496: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:1497: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c: At top level:
    _mysql.c:1519: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql__fetch_row’:
    _mysql.c:1530: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1530: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘row’
    _mysql.c:1534: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    _mysql.c:1535: error: ‘row’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1535: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_fetch_row’
    _mysql.c:1535: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1538: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:1541: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:1549: error: too many arguments to function ‘convert_row’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_fetch_row’:
    _mysql.c:1573: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘MYSQL_ROW’
    _mysql.c:1588: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1600: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    _mysql.c:1614: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_num_rows’
    _mysql.c:1614: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_character_set_name’:
    _mysql.c:1681: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_get_client_info’:
    _mysql.c:1792: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_client_info’
    _mysql.c:1792: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
    /usr/local/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:63: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_host_info’:
    _mysql.c:1807: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1811: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_host_info’
    _mysql.c:1811: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_info’:
    _mysql.c:1826: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1827: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_proto_info’
    _mysql.c:1827: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_info’:
    _mysql.c:1841: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1845: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_get_server_info’
    _mysql.c:1845: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_info’:
    _mysql.c:1862: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1863: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_info’
    _mysql.c:1863: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_insert_id’:
    _mysql.c:1899: error: ‘my_ulonglong’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1899: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
    _mysql.c:1901: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1903: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:1903: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_insert_id’
    _mysql.c:1903: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_kill’:
    _mysql.c:1920: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1922: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_kill’
    _mysql.c:1922: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_field_count’:
    _mysql.c:1941: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1943: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_num_fields’:
    _mysql.c:1958: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1959: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_num_rows’:
    _mysql.c:1974: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:1975: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:2004: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2005: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:2007: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_ping’
    _mysql.c:2007: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_query’:
    _mysql.c:2028: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2030: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_real_query’
    _mysql.c:2030: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_select_db’:
    _mysql.c:2058: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2060: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_select_db’
    _mysql.c:2060: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_shutdown’:
    _mysql.c:2079: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2081: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_shutdown’
    _mysql.c:2081: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_stat’:
    _mysql.c:2106: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2108: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_stat’
    _mysql.c:2108: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_store_result’:
    _mysql.c:2134: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2135: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:2144: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_thread_id’:
    _mysql.c:2173: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2175: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_thread_id’
    _mysql.c:2175: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_use_result’:
    _mysql.c:2195: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2196: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:2205: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_dealloc’:
    _mysql.c:2223: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_repr’:
    _mysql.c:2235: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2237: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_data_seek’:
    _mysql.c:2258: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2259: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_data_seek’
    _mysql.c:2259: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_row_seek’:
    _mysql.c:2272: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:2272: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
    _mysql.c:2274: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2275: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    _mysql.c:2280: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:2280: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_row_tell’
    _mysql.c:2280: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:2281: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_row_seek’
    _mysql.c:2281: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_row_tell’:
    _mysql.c:2293: error: ‘MYSQL_ROW_OFFSET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:2293: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘r’
    _mysql.c:2295: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2296: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘use’
    _mysql.c:2301: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    _mysql.c:2301: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c:2302: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ResultObject_dealloc’:
    _mysql.c:2310: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_free_result’
    _mysql.c:2310: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘result’
    _mysql.c: At top level:
    _mysql.c:2551: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    _mysql.c:2558: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:2565: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:2572: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:2579: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
    _mysql.c:2642: error: ‘_mysql_ResultObject’ has no member named ‘converter’
    _mysql.c:2642: error: initializer element is not constant
    _mysql.c:2642: error: (near initialization for ‘_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offset’)
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattr’:
    _mysql.c:2666: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘open’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SPMNQU/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QrpP1S-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SPMNQU/MySQL-python
```

I did see this: [Installing mysql-python on Centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380931/installing-mysql-python-on-centos) and when I tried this:

```
yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-lib
```

I got this:

```
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.43-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.43-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.43-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Removing: mysql-libs-5.5.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.7.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried this:

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

and got this:

```
Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But when I run django I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

## /usr/local/bin/python2.7

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

So clearly I do not have MySQLdb for python 2.7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380931/installing-mysql-python-on-centos

Comment: I did see that post, and tried what was suggested, and I got errors. I will update my original post with more info

Comment: try to install mysql, check that mysql and mysql client work, then the python-mysqldb

Comment: MySQL is installed and running, and I can connect to it with the mysql command line client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the yum dependencies issue with php-mysql, I recommend to switch to php-mysqlnd which have no dependency on libmysqlclient.

See: http://php.net/mysqlnd

To switch in a single transaction, you need to use yum shell:

```
# yum shell --enablerepo=remi
> remove php-mysql
> install php-mysqlnd
> run
```

Comment: This is a machine I have inherited and I really know nothing about it. I need to set up django on it, but I don't want to break anything. They use the Semantic Media Wiki, which uses PHP - If I do this could that break that?

Comment: I went ahead and did this, followed by `yum install mysql-devel` and then `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install MySQL-python` and now I cannot correct to the MySQL server and the SMW is down. ARGH!

Comment: Looks like 5.7 is now installed whereas before it was running 5.5 (`Server version: 5.5.44 MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi')` It fails on start up with `Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade` But how can I run mysql_upgrade if I can't start the server?