# MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 Install Not Recognizing mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to install MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 (from rpm) on CentOS 6.7 and I keep getting a dependency error indicating that I need mysql-connector-python 2.0 or higher.  I have installed version 2.0.2 of the connector via the directions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source.html).  What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Try this and let me know how it goes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380931/installing-mysql-python-on-centos. To avoid configuration problem, I strongly suggest you to use yum for centos, especially if you're not comfortable with centos and installation/configuration.

Comment: Not sure how that relates to my issue, but I did install MySQL 5.7 from RPM's using yum.